# Main menu in Python application

Tags: python, if-statement

I have a question about Python, I am writing app that can access specific device and change some of the parameters (lights, sound etc.) Code has a lot of "if" as it has to be user friendly, and that was only way how I imagined "menu" example

1. light
2. sound

user: 1

1. color
2. brightness

user: 1

1. red
2. green
3. yellow

code example (simplified)

```
print
select
if 1 
     print
     select
     if 1
          print
          select
```

Is there a way to go back in all of those if's? for example you went by accident to color, but want to change brightness, or control over sound, without reset of whole program? Also how I can, after every successful command sent, go back to "main menu"? while loop is not working. I am relatively new to python :D

Comment: keep a list of made choices, each entry is a level of the menu, display the menu belonging to a particular menu option like `[1,3,1]` if selected back remove the last entry and loop to the start of the menu logic, if option selected is a leaf execute and terminate the menu loop

Answer (score 0):

You could put the menu inside a while loop and for each *if* statement there should be an extra *elif* statement that checks if "back" is the input, if so a *continue* statement would start the loop over again.

```
while True:
# light or sound setting option
    setting = int(input("1. Light \n2. Sound\n"))
# if light was chosen, color/brightness choice
    if setting == 1:
        light_setting = input("1. Color \n2. Brightness \nPress \'back\' to go back\n")
#if light is chosen, which color do you choose
        if light_setting == "1":
            color = input("1. Red \n2. Green \n3. Yellow \nPress \'back\' to go back\n")

            if color == "1":
                print("red")

            elif color == "2":
                print("green")

            elif color == "3":
                print("yellow")


#condition where if "back" is the input, the menu would open from the beginning
            elif color == "back":
                continue

            else:
                print("ERROR")
#if brightness is chosen, brightness settings would open
        elif light_setting == "2":
            # Whatever the Brightness option shows
            pass

#condition where if "back" is the input, the menu would open from the beginning
        elif light_setting == "back":
            continue

        else:
            print("ERROR")
```